# How to find position of value in array

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I setvalue a `ImportJSON` to get data from an API , and I use `indexOf` to find the position title of the data table, sometime it return correct sometime not, I'm thinking about that the script run too fast for api response, so I use `Utilities.sleep(1000)` to wait, still not work

```
const tokenInfoRow = sh.getRange('A1:BG1').getValues();

const shTokenName = sh.getRange(2,(tokenInfoRow[0].indexOf('Name')+1)).getValue();
```

In my sheet `A1 == 'Address'` , `B1 == 'Name'`. Sometimes it returns correctly 1 , sometime it alert

> Exception: The starting column of the range is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways of going around it:

1. Using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)` to fetch the JSON instead of using a formula. Then you can set the values by using `range.setValues(values)`.
2. Using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` together with a `range.getValue()` on the cell where the formula is, will ensure it waits for the formula to finish.

I personally prefer the first option.

Here are examples on how to apply them:

```js
function example1() {
  const r = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://example.com/api', {
    // Parameters like headers or payload
  })

  const response = JSON.parse(r.getContentText())

  const holders = response.holders
  for (let {address, balance, share} of holders) {
    console.log(`Address "${address}" has balance ${balance} (${share}% of the total)`)
  }
}
```

```
function example2() {
  // [...]

  range.setFormula('=ImportJSON("https://example.com/api")')

  SpreadsheetApp.flush() // Forces to write the changes (including the formula)
  range.getValue() // Forces to wait for the formula

  const values = sheet.getRange('A1:BG').getValues()

  // etc.
}
```

### References

- [for...of (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Destructuring assignment (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [JSON.parse() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, param) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [SpreadsheetApp.flush() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

Comment: I was assuming the structure of the response (I didn't know what it looked like). Actually this is way simpler: `holders` is an array of objects. Each object has properties you want. I'm modifying the answer to accommodate for that. Also, I'm not too sure what are you trying to achieve, so my help will be limited because of that.

Comment: Thank you for your remind, I already deleted it . I'm trying to setValue all data from api to sheet cell as a table data, so that I can get getValues array of title ( first row of table ) and find indexOf('holders') without return -1 as I mentioned at the beginning :(

Comment: The thing is: depending on what you'd like to use this information for, you may not even need to set the values to the spreadsheet: you can use the values directly (see edited answer). What is your project? What's the final goal?

Comment: I understand my way is quite redundant , but I'm newbie so I need to write it down the sheet look at it and code what I see step by step . so I often use ImportJSON instead of UrlFetchAPP, I'm not good at working with array or object. The disadvantage of this is that calling api through ImportJSON usually slower than script so I miss data

Comment: I complete my project this way already , if you have any suggestion for me to solve issue above, that's will be great because I'm too lazy to fix everything toward we discuss. If that's the only way I think I also have to fix. I appreciate your help indeed , it's very helpful <3

Comment: I fixed it successfully , no error and project ran super quick to complete. Tks for your advise again

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. If you plan on using Apps Script more, I'd recommend you to read a JavaScript tutorial which will allow you to better understand what is going on and how to use it. [The `javascript` tag's info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info) has a nice list of them.

Answer (score 0):

To find the position of an element in an array, you use the indexOf() method. This method returns the index of the first occurrence the element that you want to find, or -1 if the element is not found.

Comment: the point is my sheet A1 == 'Address' , B1 == 'Name' . the first time I run script it returned -1, but I run again it worked , it is inconsistent